# Create UDEV rule for device with multiple tty ports

Tags: usb, tty, usb-modem, udev

I have a usb modem that creates several ttyACM connections when plugged in. I have made a udev rule to create a symlink to the ttyACM file, however I don't know how to tell which tty file it will link to.

Here is my rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1bc7", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0021", SYMLINK="cellmodem0", MODE="0666"
```

Here is the current output of ls -l /dev

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           7 Feb 11 12:35 cellmodem0 -> ttyACM3
```

I expect this to be pointing to ttyACM0 not ACM3, as ACM0 is the modem's primary port as shown by the following mmcli output:

```
-------------------------
System   |         device: '/sys/devices/3530000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.1'
         |        drivers: 'cdc_acm'
         |         plugin: 'Telit'
         |   primary port: 'ttyACM0'
         |          ports: 'ttyACM3 (at), ttyACM0 (at)'
-------------------------
```

TL;DR: How do you deal with udev rules on devices that use multiple ttyACM ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Using `udevadm info /dev/<relevent port>` you are able to see the path of the device. For me it was: `/devices/3530000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0` for ttyACM0, the port I actually want to map to. This path would be mostly the same for all the ports created except the index in ttyACMx and 1-1.1:1.x will be different. For my device the primary port will always us x = 0 for 1-1.1:1.x.

So, I added a statement to the udev rule: `DEVPATH=="/devices/3530000.xhci/usb1/1-1/1-1.*/1-1.*:1.0/tty/ttyACM*"`. Only the primary port would statisfy this criteria because I listed 1-1.*:1.0.